# MUI pop over not appearing on React-Table Cell click(AnchorEl error)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-table

making a table that looks like this

[image: Table Pic]

I am using React-Table and MUI as libraries for my UI

Now having issue in calling the Popover when the ... button is clicked

the function that invokes the popover is

```
usersMore = (row) => (event) => {
    this.setState({
      anchorEl: event.currentTarget,
      open: !this.state.open,
    });
  };
```

And Code for PopOver Is

```
        <Popper
          open={this.state.open}
          anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
          placement={"bottom-start"}
          transition
        >
          {({ TransitionProps }) => (
            <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
              <Paper elevation={3}>
                Something
              </Paper>
            </Fade>
          )}
        </Popper>
```

Whenever I click the Cell (code below) I get the error

```
Material-UI: The `anchorEl` prop provided to the component is invalid.
The anchor element should be part of the document layout.
Make sure the element is present in the document or that it's not display none.
```

Code for Setting up this cell is:

```
{
        Header: "",
        accessor: "id",
        Cell: ({ row }) => {
          const { id } = row.values;
          return (
            <DetailsButton key={id} onClick={this.usersMore(row)}>
              <MoreIcon src={more}></MoreIcon>
            </DetailsButton>
          );
        },
      },
```

I have tried many things but gotten absolutely nowhere I even tried replacing popover to a simple div that has absoloute but it aint working ar well, tried putting pop over in the cell itself still, no luck

Comment: That was an issue for material color picker and somebody made a fix on the github repo 
heres is the link to the [PR](https://github.com/mikbry/material-ui-color/pull/26/files) may be this could helps